# Programmatically Rename activeX text box "(name)" field

Tags: vba, excel

How can I programmatically rename an ActiveX text box? I'm referring to the (name) field in the properties window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveX Text Boxes can be referred by their existing name or as an ordinal in the [Shapes collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834903.aspx).

If you know the text box is currently named *TextBox1* and you want to call it *TextBox99* then refer to it directly.

```
With ActiveSheet   '<-reference the worksheet properly!
    .Shapes("TextBox1").Name = "TextBox99"
End With
```

If you want to rename all of the text boxes in a worksheet then loop through all of the shapes.

```
Dim t As Long, s As Long
With ActiveSheet   '<-reference the worksheet properly!
    For s = 1 To .Shapes.Count
        If CBool(InStr(1, .Shapes(s).Name, "textbox", vbTextCompare)) Then
            t = t + 1
            .Shapes(s).Name = "MyTextBox" & Format(t, "00")
        End If
    Next s
End With
```

Note that the .Shapes collection's index is *one-based*, not *zero-based*. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, error control to ensure that you do not attempt to rename a text box as something that already exists would be prudent.

Answer (score 1):

Jeeped's answer worked great for Excel, but unfortunately not for Word (which I also needed). So here it is for Word as well:

```
Dim shp As InlineShape
On Error Resume Next
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If Not shp.OLEFormat Is Nothing And _
            shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "TextBox1" Then
        shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "TextBox99"
        End If
    Next
On Error GoTo -1
```